# Function name for creating something if it's not there yet

Tags: language-agnostic, function, coding-style, naming

From time to time I write a function that just creates something if it's not there yet and otherwise does nothing.
Names like `CreateFooIfNecessary()` or `EnsureThereIsAFoo()` do work but they feel a bit clumsy.

One could also say `GetFoo()` but that name doesn't really imply that `foo` may be created first and it only works if the function returns a handle/pointer/reference to `foo`.

Can those of you more familiar with the English language come up with a better way to name these functions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about **GetOrCreate()**

Answer (score 14):

## UPDATE

I know better these days, and so would apply Command Query Separation (CQS). CQS says that a method should *either* mutate state, *or* return a result, never both.

As a result, my current standard is:

```
Foo GetFoo(id); // Throws if Foo cannot be found for id
Foo FindFoo(id); // Returns null if the Foo cannot be found.
void CreateFoo(id[, args]); // Creates a Foo with supplied args.
```

---

## OLD POST - IGNORE

Often I use this standard:

```
GetFoo(); // Always returns a Foo, so creates if there isn't one already.
FindFoo(); // Returns null if the Foo cannot be found.
```

Especially useful in data access, when you're loading an employee or something based on a key, and it may or may not exist.

To be specific - this is a documented coding standard.  Everyone working on the codebase knows this standard and implements it in the same way.  That's how we can get away with these nice short names that are fairly generic.

Comment: Although your answer has the highest rating, I go for GetOrCreate. As you said, this has to be a coding standard; otherwise it might not be obvious.

Comment: The point of a coding standard is that it doesn't *have* to be obvious.  Prefixing a variable with underscores isn't obvious that it's a private member variable **unless you already knew that was a standard**. The idea here is you get the best of both worlds - nice short names, but a documented standard that tells people what they mean.

Comment: Arguably, GetOrCreate is a bit of an abstraction leak.  You're going to be in one of the following situations:

Comment: * Foo(s) are managed internally, and you're calling fooManager.getFoo().  If this, the caller shouldn't care.  Its a get.
* Foo(s) are managed externally, and you're allocating one: fooFactory.createFoo().  There is no get.  Create should internally cache or share, without advertising it.
* Foo(s) are singleton-ish.  There is no create.  You just get it.

In other words, be clean about who manages Foos.

Comment: Oh, and re: Neil's response, a getFoo() that can fail should throw an exception, whereas findFoo() is ok to not find it, so returning null is appropriate.

Comment: Oh the irony of having the same question as the OP and working with Prolog. Your answered looked intriguing until I read, [Command–query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) `is a principle of imperative computer programming.` and since Prolog is not imperative the answer was instantly useless for my needs.  Cont.

Comment: More specifically - if you don't know already you can think of just about every statement in Prolog as a query and a query can have all variables and will unify the variables with the answer or return false. So CQS is going in the wrong direction with Prolog. This statement: `It states that every method should either be a command that performs an action, or a query that returns data to the caller, but not both.` But that is one of the benefits of Prolog in that a query can do work and update state variables. Granted my needs are more specific than the OPs, thus the irony.

Answer (score 8):

I would go with `EnsureFoo()`.

Answer (score 3):

This is generally known as *lazy creation*. How about LazyGetFoo()?

Answer (score 3):

so you want to be a creator, right? then ...

```
LetThereBeFoo();
```

hehehe

to check if it exists

```
IsThereFoo();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think just having CreateFoo() is fine.  The documentation should indicate what the function does in different scenarios.  Look at some of the File I/O API's out there, for instance the CreateFile(...) from the Win32 API.  Based on a parameter it will create a new file or open existing one if it exists.  Yours doesn't have to be parameter based, but it's behavior can be different based on the state of the program.  So fundamentally I think yours could be along the same lines.

Answer (score 3):

Why not:

```
private FooType m_foo;

public FooType Foo
{
   get
   {
      if (this.m_foo == null)
      {
         this.m_foo = new Foo();
      }
      return this.m_foo;
   }
   set
   {
      this.m_foo = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I name these `RequireFoo()`.

Comment: I'd use this if the method *doesn't* return the value.

Answer (score 1):

In my Foo Class I would have GetExistingOrNew(Guid id)
This would return an existing Foo if its exists or return a New Foo.

Answer (score 1):

If it's clear that only one Foo object will exist, I'd just call it CreateFoo(), because you would expect multiple calls to only create the object once.

If you are returning the value, I'd just call it GetFoo(), because lazy loading is (probably) an implementation detail, and as such, shouldn't be evident in the interface.

If multiple Foo objects can be created, and they aren't being returned, then I'm not sure. Sounds like a pretty strange situation to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started to use `defineFoo()` as I got sick of `getOrCreateFoo()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `ForceGet()`

#### Meaning:

"GET".
- and "Force" meaning: if doesn't exist -> create. (And then "GET")

#### Chronologically, Meaning:

1. if doesn't exist: `Force` create
2. `Get`

idk let me know if it makes sense to some people

Answer (score -4):

Seriously:

```
issetFoo();
```

Taking the Piss:

```
AreWeThereYetFoo(); helloFoo(); booFoo();
```