# "GetOrCreate" - does that idiom have an established name?

Tags: c#, c++, design-patterns, idioms

Ok, consider this common idiom that most of us have used many times (I assume):

```
class FooBarDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<String, FooBar> fooBars;

    ...

    FooBar GetOrCreate(String key)
    {
        FooBar fooBar;

        if (!fooBars.TryGetValue(key, out fooBar))
        {
            fooBar = new FooBar();
            fooBars.Add(key, fooBar);
        }

        return fooBar;
    }
}
```

Does it have any kind of established name?

(Yes, it's written in C#, but it can be "easily" transferred to C++. Hence that tag.)

Comment: I always call it exactly that: GetOrCreate.

Comment: Doing C++, I always seem to have to use `std::map<T>::find()` because that stupid `std::map<T>::operator[]()` adds missing values and I just want to find those already there. Doing C#, I always seem to need "get-or-create" and have to write the above, since no operation as easy as that beautiful `std::map<T>::operator[]()` is available. Isn't that strange?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238386/function-name-for-creating-something-if-its-not-there-yet/1238547#1238547

Comment: @sbi: Not only does `std::map<T>::operator[]()` add missing values, it also replaces what was already there. In some cases that's fine, but not for `GetOrCreate` - then you **must** use `std::map<T>::find()`.

Comment: @Johann: It only replaces if you write to the reference handed out by `std::map<T>::operator[]()`. If you just read from it, this doesn't happen.

Comment: @sbi: Except for the first time it's used, then it'll insert the default value for the `second` type, so by querying the map using `[]`  you cannot know if it's a new or old value.

Comment: @Johann: Yep. But sometimes that's fine. (Like when `Value` is a container itself, to which you want to add something.) Just today I wrote an extension method `public static Value GetOrCreate<Key, Value>(this IDictionary<Key, Value> dict, Key key)`. I feel much better now. `:)`

Comment: I read "getOrCreate" in your question title and knew immediately what it meant, so the name can't be that bad.

Comment: I think you should just call it "GetValue" because you're ensuring it. It doesn't matter if it needs to be created or is already there, because the result is the same.

Comment: I usually use 'void ensureXXXX();' before/while accessing if I ever need something like this. But in the case of lazy accessors, I can live with just calling it e.g. 'T const& getXXX() const'. After all, that's what we have encapsulation _for_ in the fist place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lazy Loading

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly lazy-loading. Maybe smart lazy-loading.

Comment: Lazy initialization or specialized, lazy evaluation either case lazy is definitly the word.

Answer (score 9):

I always call such functions `obtainSomething()`.

Answer (score 9):

It sort of depends why you're doing it - the idiom is one I've seen be called memoization, caching, initialisation on demand, create on first use. Normally I call the method "ensureFoo" rather than "GetOrCreate"

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of overall programming name for the high level pattern, but Perl has this wonderful behavior called [Autovivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) - namely, automatically creating hash (map) key with undefined value when you're querying the value of non-existing key in the hash.