# Calling a function on standard map element without inserting it first

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

Is the following code OK?

```
class A
{
  public:
    A();
    void foo();
};

map<int,A> m;
m[0].foo();
```

Or do I have to do the following:

```
map<int,A> m;
m[0] = A();
m[0].foo();
```

---

And also, can I do this:

```
map<int,A> m;
A a = m[5];
```

And how about access by reference:

```
void foo(A & a);
map<int,A> m;
foo(m[5]);
```

Comment: Has been discussed today already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639544/why-does-stdmap-operator-create-an-object-if-the-index-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

map::operator [] will create a new value on the fly if it doesn't already exist.  So all of your code examples will work.

That said, this example:

```
 map<int,A> m;
 m[0] = A(); // redundant
 m[0].foo();
```

is overkill as the second line is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are all valid usages. `operator[]` returns a reference to the value half of the key-value pair that either already existed or was inserted by the `operator[]` itself in the call.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the '[]' operator of a std::map, a new object will be default-constructed automatically if no item with the specified ID exists yet.