# initialize std::map value when its key does not exist

Tags: c++, constructor, stdmap

I read in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639544/why-does-stdmap-operator-create-an-object-if-the-key-doesnt-exist) that *the std::map operator[] create an object if the key doesn't exist* !

1st of all may I know where I can find a reference for this claim?(Although I know it is true)

**Next, imagin the following code snippet:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<map>

class Value {
//..
    int some_member; //is used for any purpose that you like
    std::vector<int> some_container;
public:
    Value(int some_member_) :
            some_member(some_member_) {
        std::cout << "Hello from the one-argument constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Value() {
        std::cout << "Hello from the no argument constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    void add(int v) {
        some_container.push_back(v);
    }
    int getContainerSize()
    {
        return some_container.size();
    }

//...
};

//and somewhere in the code:

class A {
public:
    std::map<int, Value> myMap;

    void some_other_add(int j, int k) {
        myMap[j].add(k);
    }
    int getsize(int j)
    {
        return myMap[j].getContainerSize();
    }

};
//and the program actually works
int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << "Size of container in key 2 = " << a.getsize(2) << std::endl;
    a.some_other_add(2, 300);
    std::cout << "New Size of container in key 2 = " << a.getsize(2) << std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

output:

```
Hello from the no argument constructor
Size of container in key 2 = 0
New Size of container in key 2 = 1
```

I can see from the above output that the no-argument constructor is invoked.

**My question is:** Is there any way to invoke the one-argument constructor of map's Value(s) ?

thank you

Comment: Here's a definitive reference: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> may I know where I can find a reference for this claim?

This is what the C++11 Standard mandates. Per paragraph 23.4.4.3:

> ```
> T& operator[](const key_type& x);
> ```
>
> 1 *Effects*: If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> T& operator[](key_type&& x);
> ```
>
> 5 *Effects*: If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(std::move(x), T())` into
>   the map.

Concerning the second question:

> Is there any way to invoke the one-argument constructor of map's Value(s) ?

You could do this in C++03:

```
void some_other_add(int j, int k) {
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(j, Value(k)));
}
```

And use the [`emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) member function in C++11:

```
myMap.emplace(j, k);
```

Comment: Andy, thanks for the answer. I guess the only solution for C++03 is the one you just mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

You'll find a helpful description of `std::map<…>::operator[]` at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

I assume you want to *conditionally* add a Value using a non-default constructor, i.e., when the corresponding key isn't present in the map.

#### C++03

```
std::map<int, Value>::iterator i = myMap.find(j);
if (i == myMap.end())
    i = myMap.insert(std::map<int, Value>::value_type(j, 123)).first;
i->add(k);
```

#### C++11

```
auto i = myMap.find(j);
if (i == myMap.end())
    i = myMap.emplace(j, 123).first;
i->add(k);
```

In both cases, newly inserted `Value`s will have some_member == 123.

Comment: Marcelo +1 for the reference. The solution is also correct. many thanks

Comment: You don't need the find(), emplace() does that already in std::map. You'll also get a compiler error for your code because emplace returns a pair of <iterator, success> which isn't the same as what find() returns