# How to check the existence of a matching in map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I want to know whether a matching `m1[0]` have been assigned.I try it in this way and it prints "1", which seems to be correct. Is it the proper way to do it?Or any better solution?

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    map<int, char> m1;
    //cout << m1[0] << endl;
    if(m1[0] == NULL) cout << "1" << endl;
    else cout << "0" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does std::map operator\[\] create an object if the key doesn't exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639544/why-does-stdmap-operator-create-an-object-if-the-key-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not checking the existence of the key, you're just checking whether the value mapped to the key is `NULL` (i.e. `'\0'` for `char`).

You should use [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find):

```
auto it = m1.find(0);
if (it != m1.end()) std::cout << "0: " << it->second << "\n";
else cout << "Not found." << endl;
```

And note that [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will insert a `value_type` object if the key does not exist. In this case the value will be [value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), for `char` it'll be zero-initialized, i.e. `'\0'`. So `m1[0]` will do the insertion at first, then `m1[0] == NULL` will return `true`, that's why your code seems to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use `m1.find(key)`, it will return `m1.end()` if there's no result.

Besides, you could use `m1.at(key)` instead of `m1[key]`, and it will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception if there's no such element.

Answer (score 1):

Use [map::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) and check if it is unequal to [map::end](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/end/).

Answer (score 1):

As other said, use map::find or map::at to check for the existence of an element. I just wanted to mention (but I can't comment yet) that the [] operator adds the given element if it doesn't exists so you can't use it for checks as it will modify your map.

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct: if `0` isn't already in the map then your code adds it with value `0`. Since `0` is equal to `NULL`, this means your code is testing whether the map assigns value `0` to the key `0`. It is not testing whether the key `0` was already in the map.

To test whether a key is present in a map, use the `count()` function. This returns `1` if the key is present and `0` otherwise.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    map<int, char> m1;
    count << (m1.count(0) ? "0" : "1") << '\n';
}
```